# Magento - Should I stop to write JS/CSS directly in the backend in CMS pages?

Tags: javascript, css, cms, cms-pages

In Magento you can create CMS pages. It is also possible to add CSS and JS code, directly to the page, which I sometimes do for rather smaller changes and style fixes and such, because then that specific code is only loaded on this page and not on any others where it is not needed.

Also it is way faster than the normal way and I don't need to push it via git which can take ages because our agency is slow, and it costs us money if they have to deal with git.

But now our agency don't want us to do this anymore, because they say it is dirty. If it is dirty, then why is it possible and not blocked by magento?

And how am I supposed to add a code which should only render on a specific CMS page?

How should I argue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my opinion. It should not be used as a reference in no way.
There is no silver bullet solution here.
As you already stated, this is a fast and cheap way to get your page to look ok.
Indeed it's cleaner to have the css and js in separate files not in the content.
But clean is not cheap nor fast.
I guess it's a matter of priorities here.
The drawbacks I see in keeping this approach is that on a theme facelift your inline styles and js may not work or look really ugly.
There is also the chance a content editor can break stuff if he/she is not paying attention.
As a developer, I am indeed against this practice as I ended up fixing stuff like this and it took more than it would have if it was done clean from the beginning.
But as a website owner (which I am not, but I'm trying to impersonate one) I totally understand this approach and I would assume the risk of things breaking in case this saves me a lot of time and money.